# Angular - how to create a table resizable column and remember the width and size

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, angular-directive, resizable

I am developing an Angular application where we can add or remove columns according to user choice and priority.

I want to create a table with a resizable columns width and store the resized column in the local storage so that the user can see the same width when he/she visit again.

Currently I am using below directive to resize columns.

[Create Resizable Table Columns with Angular Directives](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/create-resizable-table-columns-with-angular-directives-a9e0f5c1cbf7)

I am stuck how to store column with in storage and use same width when user revisit.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to explicitly store the values in `localStorage` or in some cloud database, depending on how broadly you want to remember.

You may need some method of identifying each column in your storage. This could be done with an additional `Input`.

You can retrieve these values in the `ngOnInit` function:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'th[resizable]',
  templateUrl: './resizable.component.html',
})
export class ResizableComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  @HostBinding('style.width.px')
  width: number | null = null;
  @Input('key') key: string | null = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.key) {
      const value = localStorage.getItem(this.key)
      if (value) {
        this.width = parseInt(value) // Values stored as strings
      }
    }
  }

  onResize(width: any) {
    this.width = width;
    if (this.key) {
      localStorage.setItem(this.key, width.toString())
    }
  }
}
```